# Tensorflow 2 Object Detection API Low mAP

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api, roboflow

I am trying to train a faster r-cnn model using the Tensorflow 2.0 Object Detection however I am getting extremely low mAP at 0.01.

I have had a look at the training images in Tensorboard and the training images do not look to be loaded in correctly or I have done something wrong in the configuration file.  . I am following the RoboFlow tutorial using the Hardhat sample dataset. This is my colab notebook (https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cjHpLYq8NAEce36mJGGg0Lec31wSdtF9?usp=sharing).

The top image shows an image that was used in the training dataset that has been loaded in Tensorboard and the image below that is the original.

[image: Training Image loaded in tensorboard]

[image: Original Image in Roboflow Hard Hat Sample]

I am completely new to this and I am unsure where I am going wrong. Below is the configuration file that I am using.

```
model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 3
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 640
        max_dimension: 640
        pad_to_max_dimension: true
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_resnet101_keras'
      batch_norm_trainable: true
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
        share_box_across_classes: true
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
    use_static_shapes: true
    use_matmul_crop_and_resize: true
    clip_anchors_to_image: true
    use_static_balanced_label_sampler: true
    use_matmul_gather_in_matcher: true
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 2000
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: .013333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint_version: V2
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/content/models/research/deploy/faster_rcnn_resnet101_v1_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }

  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
  use_bfloat16: true  # works only on TPUs
}

train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/content/train/Workers_label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/train/Workers.tfrecord"
  }
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  batch_size: 1;
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/content/train/Workers_label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/content/valid/Workers.tfrecord"
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: I have found an answer regarding the image distortion https://stackoverflow.com/a/63694776/9967297, however I am still not sure why the mAP is extremely low?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your training output, it looks like you should try one of a few things:

1. The dataset you used was only 100 images. Try increasing its size via [augmentation](https://blog.roboflow.com/boosting-image-detection-performance-with-data-augmentation/) (or, in this case, [using the full dataset](https://public.roboflow.com/object-detection/hard-hat-workers) instead which is over 7000 images).
2. Each epoch is taking less than a second so your total training time was less than 5 minutes. You could try boosting `num_steps` from 2,000 to 20,000 or 100,000. From prior experience, these TF2 models tend to take quite a while to converge.
3. Try a different model (I've seen [YOLOv5](https://blog.roboflow.com/how-to-train-yolov5-on-a-custom-dataset/) and [YOLOv4](https://blog.roboflow.com/training-yolov4-on-a-custom-dataset/) converge much more quickly on smaller datasets due to their [built in augmentations](https://blog.roboflow.com/yolov4-data-augmentation/)).